# 1 double throw switch 3 lights one position only 2 of the same 3 lights in the other position

Tags: lighting, switch

Can I wire a double throw switch so three lights are on in one position, but only two of the same three lights are on in the other position?

Comment: How are you going to turn off the two lights?

Comment: Where are you on this planet? Also, how are these lights connected to the switch box?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean to use a three-position switch so that you can also turn all the lights off, the answer is -- yes, you can do this, but it is expensive and moderately difficult.

You need to use a double-pole double-throw center-off wall switch. These are available from Leviton and Grainger for about $55 to $105. I couldn't find a cheaper vendor.

There are several ways to wire it. Here is one:

[image: abstract wiring diagram $55]

In the down position, lamps 1 and 2 are lit. In the up position, all three lamps are lit.

For my money, I would just use two single-pole single-throw switches in a 2-gang box. You could connect two lamps to one switch and one lamp to the other, or you could wire them like this:

[image: abstract wiring diagram $10]

With A and B off, all three lamps are dark. With A off and B on, all three lamps are dark.

With A on and B off, lamps 1 and 2 are lit and lamp 3 is dark.

With A and B on, all three lamps are lit.

Answer (score 0):

edited 'cause the comments showed I was incorrect in trying to get a single-pole to do the job.
I think a double-pole, triple throw switch will work, albeit with careful wiring  but so far I can't find one under $40 (cheaper ones are momentary, "center off" style)  unless you are willing to use a [industrial style](http://www.powergeneratorsdirect.com/search/?q=sp3t%20switch&minPrice=1&maxPrice=1000&page=2&pi=2), which may not meet housing code.

Comment: I don't want to be rude but a single-pole switch will not work. With a single pole there is just no way to separate the two-lamp load from the one-lamp load.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri  I think you're confusing 'throw' and 'pole'  . The single pole is the hot feed coming in.  Tie nothing to first throw position-- off position.  Tie lamps 2 & 3 to both the second and third throws, and tie lamp 1 to just the third throw.

Comment: You have all three lamps tied together at the third throw. There is no way to energize any lamp without lighting all of them.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri  oops, you're correct. I'll need a dptt .